# How do I reinitialize a singleton object on an interval

Tags: .net, web-services, asynchronous, singleton, lucene.net

I am setting up a WCF web service that hosts a [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net) / [AzureDirectory](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-Library-for-83562538) search engine.

For speed purposes, the recommended way to use `AzureDirectory` is to have an singleton `IndexSearcher` instance that can be used by all service calls.  Here is what I have to do that:

```
public class LuceneHelper
{    
    private static IndexSearcher _searcher;
    public static IndexSearcher searcher
    {
        get
        {
            if (_searcher == null)
                initSearcher();
            return _searcher;
        }
    }
    public static void initSearcher()
    {
        _searcher = new IndexSearcher(azureDirectory);
    }
    ...
}
```

Since that object caches the index it is searching I need to reinitialize that object on an interval asynchronously from any client calls... like every minute or so.  So I tried to setup a process running in another thread on my azure instance that does this...

```
LuceneHelper.initSearcher();
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(60000);
    LuceneHelper.initSearcher();
}
```

I can tell from my testing that they both are working but independently of each other. So I guess there is an IndexSearcher in my web service and one in my worker thread.

**My Question:** Is there a way to run my infinite 'while' statement in my webservice asynchronously or any other way to reinitialize an object without a call from a client?

Comment: why do you need to re-open the IndexSearcher on an interval? It looks like you want Near-Real time searching with Lucene, http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/06/lucenes-near-real-time-search-is-fast.html

Comment: By initializing IndexSearcher in advance it caches the index and is what makes Lucene.Net as quick as it is. The reason I need to re-open it is to refresh that cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your direct question, yes, it's possible to have the while statement run in the background of your webservice.  All you have to do is create an instance of the [`Thread` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) and have it run your loop and store a reference to it in your application (your singleton class would be a good place).

That said, I wouldn't recommend this, as you don't need to open/close/reopen the [`IndexSearcher` class](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html).  The recommended practice is to maintain a shared [`IndexWriter`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html) instance for the life of your app and then call the [`GetReader` method](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#getReader%28%29) to get an [`IndexReader`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html) instance on-demand (from which you can then create an `IndexSearcher`).  This is generally much faster and more maintainable than recreating the index (and it's real-time as well, as the call to `GetReader` will have all the changes to the index).

Comment: Combine this with an IndexWriter.MergedSegmentWarmer and you get the capability to do custom warm-up logic for newly created segments.

Comment: @simon-svensson I'm having trouble finding how to use IndexWriter.SetMergedSegmentWarmer. Can you share a quick example or a link to a how-to? Thanks.

Comment: Hey @SimonSvensson I was having a problem passing IndexReaderWarmer as an argument to SetMergedSegmentWarmer since IndexReaderWarmer is a non-invokable, abstract class. I was able to inherit from it and override some stuff to get it to work.  After all that it became clear that a warmer is not very helpful to me and I was able to accomplish similar effects by calling IndexWriter.GetReader()  or ReOpen.  I may misunderstand the warmer but at least it works.  Thanks for following up.